# Android EditText NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I need to take data from my **EditText**, which I placed inside dialog.
When i try to access it I catch NullPointerException.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int imgW  ;
    int imgH  ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void OnToolButtonClick(View button)
    {
        switch (button.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btn1:

            final Dialog commentDialog = new Dialog(this);
            commentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.reply);
            Button okBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

            okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final    EditText     w=  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
                    final    EditText     h=  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogH);

                    try {
                        imgW =  Integer.parseInt(w.getText().toString());
                        imgH = Integer.parseInt( h.getText().toString());   

                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        imgH=0;
                        imgW=0;
                    }

                    Log.i("Size" ,  " w "+ imgW + " h " + imgH);
                    //  drawing_panel_params

                    commentDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button cancelBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    commentDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            commentDialog.show();

            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Main Layout**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.edittext.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="OnToolButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/Start_dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout for dialog**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialogW"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/Wight"
        android:lines="3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialogH"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/Height"
        android:lines="3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to know why is this happening..??

Comment: Please post your error message as well

Comment: when you post your code here... make sure that formatted correctly.... f you don't want to do that manually let your eclipse do that... select whole code and press "CTRL + I" and then post here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 final EditText w= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
 final EditText h= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialogH);
```

to

```
 final EditText w= (EditText)commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
 final EditText h= (EditText)commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogH);
```

Your `dialogW` and `dialogH` are in `reply` layout which is inflated in `commentDialog`. You need to use the `View` in which you inflate the layout in which your `EditText` exist

Answer (score 0):

you missed commentDialog in findviewbyId

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int imgW  ;
int imgH  ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void OnToolButtonClick(View button)
{
    switch (button.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btn1:

        final Dialog commentDialog = new Dialog(this);
        commentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.reply);
        Button okBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final    EditText     w=  (EditText)commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
                final    EditText     h=  (EditText) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogH);

                try {
                    imgW =  Integer.parseInt(w.getText().toString());
                    imgH = Integer.parseInt( h.getText().toString());   

                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    imgH=0;
                    imgW=0;
                }

                Log.i("Size" ,  " w "+ imgW + " h " + imgH);
                //  drawing_panel_params

                commentDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button cancelBtn = (Button) commentDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                commentDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        commentDialog.show();

        break;
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I believe that it won't be finding the view as your not using findViewById() with the view that you set for the dialog.

I.e. change

```
commentDialog.setContentView(R.layout.reply);
```

to

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reply, null);
commentDialog.setContentView(view);
```

and then change

```
final EditText w = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
final EditText h = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogH);
```

to

```
final EditText w = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogW);
final EditText h = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogH);
```

Give that a go and see if you no longer get a NullPointerException.